# expand-archive successfully expands, but oddly returns error

Tags: powershell, error-handling, unzip

In a script I'm trying to unzip a zip file and even though it successfully unzips the files into the folder, it returns error. I get the failed message of the IF statement (snippet below). I've tried it with and without the -Force option and get the same result. The zip file is verified via sha256 hash and the unzipped folder size matches the original folder size, so I know it's not a corrupt zip file. Any ideas what's going on here and how to resolve it?

Script snippet:

```
# Extract downloaded zip file
if (Expand-Archive -LiteralPath $download_file_path -Force -DestinationPath $download_folder) {
  echo "File extraction successful" >> $log_path
} else {
  echo "File extraction FAILED! Exiting script." >> $log_path
  exit
}
```

Console output:

```
    Directory: C:\WINDOWS\TEMP


Mode                 LastWriteTime         Length Name                                                                 
----                 -------------         ------ ----                                                                 
d-----         1/10/2022   1:10 AM                app_data-20220110011021
```

Custom log file entry:

```
File extraction FAILED! Exiting script.
```

Answer (score 0):

You should not use [Expand-Archive](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/powershell/module/microsoft.powershell.archive/expand-archive) in an `if()` construct to catch any possible errors.
Best use a `try{..} catch{..}` for that:

```
# Extract downloaded zip file
try {
    Expand-Archive -LiteralPath $download_file_path -Force -DestinationPath $download_folder -ErrorAction Stop
    Add-Content -Path $log_path -Value "File extraction successful" -PassThru
} 
catch {
    Add-Content -Path $log_path -Value "File extraction FAILED! Exiting script." -PassThru
    # you can view the error or write it to the log file:
    Write-Warning $_.Exception.Message
}
```

Note:

- `-ErrorAction Stop` makes the code execute the catch block on both terminating and non-terminating errors.
- Inside the catch block, you can examine the error through the `$_` automatic variable as in `$_.Exception.Message`